# How are the iterators of an Hash Set ordered?

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

How are the iterators of an `HashSet` ordered?

Suppose I got these:

```
HashSet<E> set = new HashSet<E>();
Iterator<E> it=set.iterator();
```

Does `it.next()` return elements in a certain order? And how does it works actually?

Comment: It orders the element into buckets by the `hashCode`.

Comment: It will just return the elements as they were stored before, without order. `TreeMap` does have order.

Comment: It stores the elements in an order that will deliberately change at the worst possible time to punish people who depend on unspecified behavior.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#iterator%28%29):

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this set. The elements are
>   returned in no particular order.

Also, some SO posts:

- [What causes the slightly unpredictable ordering of the iterator() for the java.util.HashSet and HashMap.keySet() classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418896/what-causes-the-slightly-unpredictable-ordering-of-the-iterator-for-the-java-u)
- [Iteration order of HashSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704597/iteration-order-of-hashset)