# Ordering of elements in Java HashSet

Tags: java, collections, hashset, linkedhashset

Why do the second and third sets preserve order:

```
Integer[] j = new Integer[]{3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
LinkedHashSet<Integer> i = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
Collections.addAll(i,j);
System.out.println(i); 

HashSet<Integer> hi = new HashSet<Integer>(i);
System.out.println(hi); 

LinkedHashSet<Integer> o = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(hi);
System.out.println(o);
```

Here's the output I get:

```
3,4,5,6,7,8,9
3,4,5,6,7,8,9
3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2704640/1048330

Comment: *In general*, Maps (or Sets) implemented using hashing have no well-defined order. (Although *some* implementations, e.g. LinkedHashSet, have an as-added order; see the [class-level] documentation for guarantees, if any. The behavior is discussed in both the HashSet and LinkedHashSet documentation.)

Comment: Behrang is correct in saying this is a coincidence.  Mainly from the fact that integer hash codes are order preserving.  Try adding more than a few numbers as well as larger numbers to the hash set and see if the order of the elements is preserved.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The second one (just using `HashSet`) is only a coincidence. From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; ***in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time***. This class permits the null element.

The third one (`LinkedHashSet`) is [designed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to be like that:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted into the set. (An element e is reinserted into a set s if s.add(e) is invoked when s.contains(e) would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)

Answer (score 6):

@Behrang's answer is good but to be more specific, the only reason why the `HashSet` seems to be in the same order as the `LinkedHashSet` is that `integer.hashCode()` happens to be the integer value itself so the numbers happen to be in order in the `HashSet` internal storage.  This is *highly* implementation specific and as @Behrang says, really a coincidence.

For example, if you use `new HashSet<>(4)` which sets the initial number of buckets to be 4 (instead of 16) then you might have gotten the following output:

```
HashSet<Integer> hi = new HashSet<Integer>(4);
...
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[8, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

If you had stuck in values >= 16, you might get something like this:

```
Integer[] j = new Integer[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 16 };
...
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 16]
[16, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[16, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```