# While using Set in Java(Selenium),I am getting values from bottom to top--instead of top to bottom

Tags: java, selenium

```
    Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<Integer>();
    set.add(41);
    set.add(52);
    set.add(33);

    Iterator<Integer> iterate=set.iterator();
    System.out.println(iterate.next());
    System.out.println(iterate.next());
    System.out.println(iterate.next());
```

O/P-> 33 52 41
Instead I should get 41, 52 and 33

Plz explain why it is printing in this manner or I did something wrong.

Comment: Usually sets are unordered collections. Look up LinkedHashSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to retain insertion order in your `Set`.
[LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) is designed to retain insertion order. From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the
>   order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order).
>   Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted
>   into the set. (An element e is reinserted into a set s if s.add(e) is
>   invoked when s.contains(e) would return true immediately prior to the
>   invocation.)

Kindly refer to the question [Ordering of elements in Java HashSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345651/ordering-of-elements-in-java-hashset) to know about ordering in [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). From the [JavaDocs:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table
>   (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the
>   iteration order of the set; **in particular, it does not guarantee that
>   the order will remain constant over time.** This class permits the null
>   element.